# How to get the email sent day using office js

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

The namespace `Office.context.mailbox.item` only expose `dateTimeCreated` and `dateTimeModified`

How do I access to the date the mail is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature you requested is not a part of the product. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

You can, however, retrieve this value via Microsoft Graph API, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}`. It returns a property called `sentDateTime`, which I think is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, "dateTimeCreated" is the property of “the date the mail is sent”. Please see the picture as below:
[image]
Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried that. If you drafted an email without sending on say 16-06-2018 and send it on 17-06-2018. The dateTimeCreated field will return 16-06-2018 instead of 17-06-2018 which is the actual sent day. It is close though.

Comment: I'll test it again and get back to you as soon as possible.